# C++20 Concept for checking presence of private class members

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, factory-method

Consider the situation of having some `class A` together with a factory `class Factory`. `A` is supposed to have only private constructors (to prevent the user from creating such an object), and is `friend`s with `Factory`, who can then construct Objects of type `A`.

`A` also has some private attribute which cannot be set in in `A`'s constructor (because the value is not known yet), but will be computed by `Factory` and then set correctly before `A` is returned.

Now i have the situation that I have similar classes `B`,`C`, ... to `A` that should also be constructed by `Factory`, which will thus be a `template`.

So the situation is currently

```
template<typename T>
class Factory {
public:
    T get() {
        T t;
        void* computed_value = nullptr; // suppose we compute a
        t._value = computed_value;
        return t;
    }
};

class A {
    // Some public methods for the user
    friend class Factory<A>;
private:
    A() : _value(nullptr) {} //initialised with nullptr since we have no meaningful value (yet)
    void* _value;
    // some more attributes that will correctly be initialsed by the default constructor
};

class B {
    //Some public methods for the user
    friend class Factory<B>;
private:
    B(): _value(nullptr) {} //initialised with nullptr since we have no meaningful value (yet)
    void* _value;
    // Some more attributes that will correctly be initialised by the default constructor
};

void foo() {
    Factory<A> a_factory;
    A a_elem = a_factory.get();

    Factory<B> b_factory;
    B b_elem = b_factory.get();
}
```

Actually, an instance of `Factory<A>` also stores some values that are used in the construction of some `A`, that are set by the constructor of `Factory`, this is why i use instances of the `Factory` and not `static` methods.

Now comes the point: I would like to use Concepts in order to constrain the `template<typename T>` that is used by the `Factory`, so something like:

```
template<typename T>
concept Factorable = requires (T t) {
    std::same_as<void*, decltype(t._value)>;
};

template<Factorable t>
class Factory { //...
```

As expected, this does not work, because the corresponding required expressions are private and thus not available, `Factorable<A>` will just be `false`.

Now, hanging the attribute and constructor of `class A` to `public` will thus lead to a nice generic `Factory` and the below (correct) code

```
template<Factorable T>
class Factory {
public:
    T get() {
        T t;
        void* computed_value = nullptr; // suppose we compute a
        t._value = computed_value;
        return t;
    }
};

class A {
    // Some public methods for the user
    template<Factorable T>
    friend class Factory;
public:
    A() : _value(nullptr) {} //initialised with nullptr since we have no meaningful value (yet)
    void* _value;
    // some more attributes that will correctly be initialsed by the default constructor
};

class B {
    //Some public methods for the user
    template<Factorable T>
    friend class Factory;
public:
    B(): _value(nullptr) {} //initialised with nullptr since we have no meaningful value (yet)
    void* _value;
    // Some more attributes that will correctly be initialised by the default constructor
};

void use() {
    Factory<A> a_factory;
    A a_elem = a_factory.get();

    Factory<B> b_factory;
    B b_elem = b_factory.get();
}
```

Note the subtlety that we now had to declare all generic variants of `Factory` as a friend of classes `A` and `B`, since `Factory<A>` cannot be evaluated while defining class `A` itself and thus not explicitly declared as a `friend`. I am however fine with this, since in the implementation of the `Factory<T>` we will not access other classes than `T` anyways (It would however be nice to achieve a `friend class Factory<A>`, but this is not my priority).

But this approach leads to the *massive* problem that a user can now generate instances of `A` by just calling its constructor, which just sets `_value = nullptr`, so we get 'invalid' instances of `A` that may lead to undefined behaviour etc. So this is *really* not the way to go for, although the use of the `concept`s in above expression would be nice.

So my question now is:
**How can I achieve both of the above, in order have private constructors and attributes, but still use concepts**

I found out that `concept`s *are* actually context-sensitive, in the sense that the required expressions are checked in the invoking context, so in fact the following code will correctly compile

```
template<typename T>
concept Factorable = requires (T t) {
    std::same_as<void*, decltype(t._value)>;
};


template<typename T>
class Factory {
    static_assert(Factorable<T>);
public:
    T get() {
        T t;
        void* computed_value = nullptr; // suppose we compute a
        t._value = computed_value;
        return t;
    }
};

class A {
    // Some public methods for the user
    template<typename T>
    friend class Factory;
private:
    A() : _value(nullptr) {} //initialised with nullptr since we have no meaningful value (yet)
    void* _value;
    // some more attributes that will correctly be initialsed by the default constructor
};

class B {
    //Some public methods for the user
    template<typename T>
    friend class Factory;
private:
    B(): _value(nullptr) {} //initialised with nullptr since we have no meaningful value (yet)
    void* _value;
    // Some more attributes that will correctly be initialised by the default constructor
};


void use() {
    Factory<A> a_factory;
    A a_elem = a_factory.get();

    Factory<B> b_factory;
    B b_elem = b_factory.get();
}
```

since now the compiler will first accept any typename `T` as generic and then check the `concept` for the given `T` *within the context of the class*, which will thus evaluate to true, since `Factory` is friends with both `A` and thus has access to its data members.

So this approach can actually guarantee user-safe instantiation of `class A` and throwing corresponding errors when the `static_assertion` fails to evaluate, but of course this is not the way a `concept` is intended to use, since then we basically just fall back to duck-typing as it was before the introduction of `concept`s and manually `assert` certain things, which loses the desired properties of concepts (late error throwing etc., but also losing IDE completion).

A solution would of course be to have the possibility to require the presence of `private` attributes in a `concept`, something like the following

```
//Suppose the existence of a function like std::ignore_private(expression)
template<typename T>
concept Factorable = requires (T t) {
     std::same_as<void*, decltype(std::ignore_private(t._value))>;
}
```

where `std::ignore_private` is of course completely made up (and i also don't know what syntax it actually should have), but you get the point what i actually want.

So, is there any way to express something like this in a `concept`?

At least, i could imagine that, since checking for private attributes is a `constexpr` and can also be checked at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a better solution a compromise could be to constrain the method:

```
template<typename T>
class Factory {
public:
    T get() requires Factorable<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting around a while, i came up with the following workaround, using an additional `Tester` class, that has to be declared friend by `A`:

```
template<typename T>
concept PrivateFactorable = requires (T t) {
    std::same_as<void*, decltype(t._value)>;
};

template<typename T> class Tester {
public:
    constexpr static bool factorable = PrivateFactorable<T>;
};

template<typename T>
concept Factorable = Tester<T>::factorable;


template<Factorable T>
class Factory {
public:
    T get() {
        T t;
        void* computed_value = nullptr; // suppose we compute a meaningful value here
        t._value = computed_value;
        return t;
    }
};

class A {
    // Some public methods for the user
    template<Factorable T>
    friend class Factory;
    friend class Tester<A>;
public:
    A() : _value(nullptr) {} //initialised with nullptr since we have no meaningful value (yet)
    void* _value;
    // some more attributes that will correctly be initialsed by the default constructor
};
```

This will correctly redirect `Factorable<A>` into the tester class, who can evaluate the concept withing `friend` context with `A`. The only downside is that `A` has to have yet another `friend` (and we get some more concepts in the background), but this seems okay

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it’s a compiler bug if the value of a concept depends on the lexical **location** of requesting it.

It could interfere with subsumption where that matters, but you can write the constraint **directly**:

```
template<class T> requires std::same_as<void*, decltype(T::_value)>
class Factory {…};
```

Substitution failures in a constraint cause it to be unsatisfied whether it’s in a `concept` or not.

Comment: but this does not solve the problem that `_value` is a private attribute in class `A`, so this requires clause will just always fail, or am i missing something?

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler: Isn’t `Factory<T>` a friend of `T`?